# In game loop, how do I restart game properly using nested class or loop?

Tags: python, loops, class, pygame, nested

I making a game in python3 using pygame, logic of my game happens in `run` loop.
My question is How do I make game restart, without having use nested class and loop as in example below?

I am afraid this code will use too much memory when player dies enough dies, but maybe my understanding of this code is wrong? (I assume, when player dies every time a new `game` class is made and so does new variables.

```
class Game:
    def init:
        #code goes here
    def run(self,deathcount):
        while self.running==True:
        #code goes here
        if player dies
           deathcount+=1
           game = Game()
           self.running=False
           game.run(death_count)

if name == "main":
    game = Game()
    game.run(death_count=0)
```

Comment: Just have the same game instance reset whatever game state you need to reset, don't create a new one..?

Comment: Alternatively, have `run` return when the player dies, and use a code in the main loop to restart.    `run` should just run one game and then be done.

Comment: Okey I did this way because the game class contains information about the player, which I need to reset.

Comment: Well, refactor that code out from `__init__` to e.g. `reset_player()`, and call it in the death `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach would be to have an outer loop. The outer loop runs as long as the game is not terminated. In the loop, the `Game` object is created and the application loop is executed:

```py
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        # [...]

    def run(self, death_count):
        
        quit_game = False
        game_over = False
        while not quit_game and not game_over:

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    quit_game = True

            # [...]

            if player_dies:
                game_over = True

        return quit_game
           
if name == "main":
    death_count = 0
    quit_game = False
    while not quit_game:
        game = Game()
        quit_game = game.run(death_count)
        death_count += 1
```